# Как вывести количество записей в день в MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Хочу сделать статистику регистрации юзеров в виде подобного графика:
[image: График]

Каким образом мне получить количество записей за каждый день на протяжении месяца?

Что-то вроде:

2019-03-22 - 1

2019-03-23 - 10

...

Данные в таком виде:

```
{ 
   "name" : "Alexander",
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-22T11:04:19.709Z"), 
   "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-04-29T10:22:51.953Z")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938859/mongodb-aggregate-within-daily-grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я написал это в mongo shell, в код на mongoose, думаю, сами сможете перевести

```
map = function(){
    emit(
        Date.UTC(
            this.createdAt.getFullYear(), 
            this.createdAt.getMonth(), 
            this.createdAt.getDate()
), this.name)};

const reduce = function(key, value){return value.length};
db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: {inline: 1} });
```

либо через aggregate

```
db.users.aggregate([{$group: {_id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } }, users: {$push: "$name"}}}, {$project: {usersCount: {$size: "$users"}}}])
```

Comment: наверное под задачу лучше подходит `map = function(){emit(Date.UTC(this.createdAt.getFullYear(), this.createdAt.getMonth(), this.createdAt.getDate()), this.name)};`

Comment: да, конечно, забыл что там ещё и время

Comment: или даже `${this.createdAt.getFullYear()}-${1+this.createdAt.getMonth()}-${this.createdAt.getDate()}`. поправь ответ, короч )

Comment: Спасибо большое